# Spring Boot Jetty with SSL ,Acceptor and Selector configuration not working

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, jetty, embedded-jetty

Without SSL the following configurations to configure acceptors and selectors work fine.

> server.jetty.acceptors=4
>
> server.jetty.selectors=32

But when I enable SSL , then this configuration for Jetty in Spring Boot doesnt work. Tried using

> jetty.ssl.acceptors=4
>
> jetty.ssl.selectors=32

I am using Spring Boot with Embedded Jetty. Everytime it runs it configures 1 Acceptor in SSL mode. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you expecting some kind of extreme load scenario (think over 400,000 req/s) for your spring-boot project?  It's rare to have more selectors then CPU cores.

Comment: I am concerned about the number of acceptors. I would like to make that highers so that it can hand off request in parallel to selectors. Also when I increase the number of acceptors and selectors and it is non SSL I see an increase in performance. CPU usage is less and I see all the acceptors running in parallel.

Comment: Doesn't work that way. Acceptors accept, hold, and allow for a queue, that's all. A ManagedSelector registers / selects / processes. A single ManagedSelector is often enough for 200,000 req/s (except OS's with NIO bugs). processing is determined by the threading algorithm (which changes depending on load).  What's WAY more important is your thread pool configuration.

Comment: To put it a different way, a 1 acceptor and 1 selector configuration are capable of fully saturating a 1 gigabit ethernet link.

Comment: Thanks Joakim for the explaination. Yet , i would understand that there must be a way to change the acceptors and selectors count in SSL mode. I am not sure why that is not happening. It works in non SSL mode though. Also a selector processing 200K req/sec may not ALWAYS hold true , it depends on the processing per thread.

Comment: The selector thread doesn't do the processing of the request, that's the Thread Pool and execution strategy's job.  If you have slow processing, or an old webapp that doesn't use async I/O then no amount of tinkering with the acceptors / selectors will help, only the thread pool config will help.

Comment: I tried the thread pool config but its not working in Spring Boot. Do you have resource to which I can refer to ? But I still would like to know how I can configure selectors and acceptors in SSL mode using Spring Boot. Can you please tell me how I can do it ?